# How do I install the Apache FtpServer as a service within Windows 7 (64-bit)?

Tags: apache, ftp, service, windows-7-x64

I tried everything I could think of, but I always get this error when I try to start the Apache FtpServer service.

> Windows could not start the Apache FtpServer on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 0.

Has anyone got Apache FtpServer to function as a Windows service in Windows 7 or even Windows Vista?

Note:

1. My Java_HOME environment variable is set as c:\java and I have a symbolic link, linking this directory to the longer C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17.
2. I also have another symbolic link pointing c:\ftp to the longer C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-ftpserver-1.0.3.
3. The only reason I did any of this in the first place is because I was reading that some people were having problems with spaces or long path names, but I tried physically moving the directories as well, all with the same error.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've never been to that site. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today using apache ftpser 1.0.5., the error message was "Failed installing 'ftpd' service".

The solution was to start the DOS command shell as "Administrator".